# Python - How to concatenate to a string in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

I need to "concatenate to a string in a for loop". To explain, I have this list:

```
list = ['first', 'second', 'other']
```

And inside a for loop I need to end with this:

```
endstring = 'firstsecondother'
```

Can you give me a clue on how to achieve this in python?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: A relatively old, but still interesting comparison of different concatenation techniques http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string

Answer (score 85, accepted):

That's not how you do it.

```
>>> ''.join(['first', 'second', 'other'])
'firstsecondother'
```

is what you want.

If you do it in a `for` loop, it's going to be inefficient as string "addition"/concatenation doesn't scale well (but of course it's possible):

```
>>> mylist = ['first', 'second', 'other']
>>> s = ""
>>> for item in mylist:
...    s += item
...
>>> s
'firstsecondother'
```

Comment: I need to do it in a for loop, I need to add some logic inside a for loop. It is possible to do that inside a for loop?

Comment: @André Depending on the logic you need (some transformation to the elements? some unrelated side effects?), it may make sense to pull the string construction out of the loop or create the transformed elements and then apply this to concat them. Doing this naively in a loop can be *very* bad for performance (as in, quadratic slowdown = add one string, need twice the same; it's not a good habit to get into).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is that piece of code that I was looking for.

Comment: does the join method work on ANY iterable?

Comment: As long as it contains only strings, yes. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Is there any pythonic way to return 'first + second + other'?

Comment: @steven: `' + '.join(['first', 'second', 'other'])`

Comment: Have a results list to append to, then join() it at the end.

Answer (score 8):

```
endstring = ''
for s in list:
    endstring += s
```

Comment: Inefficient, use join().

Answer (score 6):

If you must, this is how you can do it in a for loop:

```
mylist = ['first', 'second', 'other']
endstring = ''
for s in mylist:
  endstring += s
```

but you should consider using `join()`:

```
''.join(mylist)
```

Comment: Inefficient, use join().

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
endstring = ''.join(list)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I realy need to do it inside a for loop. It is possible?

Comment: Well, you coud add strings to the list inside your loop, and after it, join them. It's much more efficient (in fact, it's the recommended way) than appending the strings inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

While "".join is more pythonic, and the correct answer for this problem, it is indeed possible to use a for loop.

If this is a homework assignment (please add a tag if this is so!), and you are required to use a for loop then what will work (although is not pythonic, and shouldn't really be done this way if you are a professional programmer writing python) is this:

```
endstring = ""
mylist = ['first', 'second', 'other']
for word in mylist:
  print "This is the word I am adding: " + word
  endstring = endstring + word
print "This is the answer I get: " + endstring
```

You don't need the 'prints', I just threw them in there so you can see what is happening.