# How to get keys from multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a Python code which will translate emoji to text using a dict, but I have no idea how to get keys which are text from multiple values (emoji) in a sentence

```
emoji={
    'a':'️',
    'b':'️',
    'c':'️',
    'd':'️',
    'e':'️',
    'f':'️',
    'g':'️',
    'h':'️',
    'i':'️',
    'j':'️',
    'k':'️',
    'l':'️',
    'm':'️',
    'n':'️',
    'o':'️',
    'p':'☺️',
    'q':'️',
    'r':'️',
    's':'️',
    't':'️',
    'u':'️',
    'v':'️',
    'w':'️',
    'x':'️',
    'y':'️',
    'z':'️',
}
output_text=''
input_text=str(input('Input:'))
for letter in input_text:
    if letter in emoji.values():
        output_text=output_text+emoji.keys(letter)
    else:
        output_text=output_text+letter

print(output_text)
```

This code will go through every single character in a sentence and then it will check if he character is a emoji in the dict, if yes it will get the text (key) of the emoji (value).

Edit#1:
Updated code:

```
emoji_dict={k:v for v,k in emoji.items()}

print(emoji_dict)
input_text=str(input('Input:'))
output_text=''
for letter in input_text:
    if letter in emoji_dict:
        print(emoji_dict[letter])
        output_text=output_text+emoji_dict[letter]
    else:
        output_text=output_text+letter

print(output_text)
```

Comment: Isn't your dict actually exactly opposite what you are trying to do!

Comment: Well, actually I have an other code which use this dict to translate from text to emoji (I take a small part of the code so it would be easier to read). I know I can just write another dict but i want to know more about Python dict and also I am lazy to write another one:) Thank you for commenting on my post :D

Comment: Then you have to mention that clearly!

Comment: Thank you :D But also could you explain me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of writing another dict, do ```emoji={k:v for v,k in emoji.items()}```. Let python do it

Comment: Please update your question so it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have added your code to my code but I think there is still some problem with it.
Edit: I will edit my question with the new code included

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I'm under the impression that it is a back and forth translation table. If that is the case, consider using `str.maketrans()` and `str.translate()`. Your code will probably be shorted down to two or three lines.

Comment: @chup What's wrong with Sujay's suggestion? Please be detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the dict. Then it's a simple lookup.

```
emoji_to_letter = {v: k for k, v in emoji.items()}
```

---

Although, there are additional characters in the `emoji` values, namely U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16, that you'll need to get rid of first before you can do character lookups.

```
emoji = {k: v.strip('\ufe0f') for k, v in emoji.items()}
```

---

Lastly, [avoid building strings in a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8249539/4518341). You can you can use [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead.

```
table = str.maketrans(emoji_to_letter)
output_text = input_text.translate(table)
```

But for what it's worth, the more generic best practice is to use `''.join()` like this:

```
output_text = ''.join(emoji_to_letter.get(char, char) for char in input_text)
```

---

#### All together

```
emoji_to_letter = {v.strip('\ufe0f'): k for k, v in emoji.items()}
table = str.maketrans(emoji_to_letter)

input_text = 'bruh '
output_text = input_text.translate(table)
print(output_text)  # -> bruh c
```